# Specifying parent controller in rails_admin results in deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-admin

I noticed in my rails 6 project that adding the following to `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` results in a deprecation warning:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.parent_controller = ApplicationController.to_s

  # ...
```

Warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants ApplicationHelper, AboutHelper, GroupHelper, MapHelper, DeviseHelper, ActionText::ContentHelper, and ActionText::TagHelper.

Being able to do this is deprecated. Autoloading during initialization is going
to be an error condition in future versions of Rails.

Reloading does not reboot the application, and therefore code executed during
initialization does not run again. So, if you reload ApplicationHelper, for example,
the expected changes won't be reflected in that stale Module object.

These autoloaded constants have been unloaded.

Please, check the "Autoloading and Reloading Constants" guide for solutions.
 (called from <main> at /opt/app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

One workaround for this is to simply use `"ApplicationController"` instead of `ApplicationController.to_s`, but is there a way to do the latter approach without this deprecation warning?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right

```
# Which class should be used for the controllers
  config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationAdminController'
```

here the issue in the library [issue_link](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/3190)